# How to compare two JS array and create new JS array using changes

Tags: javascript

I have two JS arrays. They are `arr1` and `arr2`. I want to create another array called `arr3`. Now it wants to compare `arr1` and `arr2` and insert all elements which `arr2` contains and `arr1` not contain.

Example:

arr1:

```
  0:
    des: "cont1"
    note: "cont1"
    pro_code: "XXY"
  1:
    des: "cont2"
    note: "cont2"
    pro_code: "NNB"
  2:
    des: "cont4"
    note: "cont4"
    pro_code: "QQA"
  3:
    des: "cont5"
    note: "cont5"
    pro_code: "GFD"
```

arr2:

```
  0:
    des: "cont1"
    note: "cont1"
    pro_code: "XXY"
  1:
    des: "cont2"
    note: "cont2"
    pro_code: "NNB"
  2:
    des: "cont3"
    note: "cont3"
    pro_code: "QAS"
```

In `arr2` contains `pro_code: QAS`. But it is not in `arr1`. So it should be contained in `arr3`.

In `arr1` contains `arr1[4] pro_code: GFD`. it `should not` be contained in `arr3`. Becase `aar1` can contain additional elements.

Here `arr2` must contain elements that are in `arr1`. There can not additional elements in `arr2`.

Expected output:

```
const arr3 = [{
  des: "cont3",
  note: "cont3",
  pro_code: "QAS"
}
```

My tried code, not workes. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz I updated the question with `Expected output:` I am using this in vue `computed:` there `some()` is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for all `pro_code` values and filter the second array by checking if the value is not in the set.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ des: "cont1", note: "cont1", pro_code: "XXY" }, { des: "cont2", note: "cont2", pro_code: "NNB" }, { des: "cont4", note: "cont4", pro_code: "QQA" }, { des: "cont5", note: "cont5", pro_code: "GFD" }],
    array2 = [{ des: "cont1", note: "cont1", pro_code: "XXY" }, { des: "cont2", note: "cont2", pro_code: "NNB" }, { des: "cont3", note: "cont3", pro_code: "QAS" }],
    pro_codes = new Set(array1.map(({ pro_code }) => pro_code)),
    result = array2.filter(({ pro_code }) => !pro_codes.has(pro_code));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, your requirement is to filter the `arr2` and keep elements that are not in `arr1`.

```
const arr3 = arr2.filter(function(arr2item) {
  // only keep this item if it is not in arr1
  return !arr1.some(function(arr1item) {
    return arr1item.pro_code === arr2item.pro_code;
  })
});
```

```js
const arr1 = [{des: "cont1", note: "cont1", pro_code: "XXY"}, {des: "cont2", note: "cont2", pro_code: "NNB"}, {des: "cont4", note: "cont4", pro_code: "QQA"}, {des: "cont5", note: "cont5", pro_code: "GFD"}];
const arr2 = [{des: "cont1", note: "cont1", pro_code: "XXY"}, {des: "cont2", note: "cont2", pro_code: "NNB"}, {des: "cont3", note: "cont3", pro_code: "QAS"}]

const arr3 = arr2.filter(function(arr2item) {
  return !arr1.some(function(arr1item) {
    return arr1item.pro_code === arr2item.pro_code;
  })
});

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: @connexo i am not comparing the objects, but the `pro_code` string property.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another optimized solution

```js
const arr1 = [{
  des: "cont1",
  note: "cont1",
  pro_code: "XXY"
}, {
  des: "cont2",
  note: "cont2",
  pro_code: "NNB"
}, {
  des: "cont4",
  note: "cont4",
  pro_code: "QQA"
}, {
  des: "cont5",
  note: "cont5",
  pro_code: "GFD"
}];

const arr2 = [{
  des: "cont1",
  note: "cont1",
  pro_code: "XXY"
}, {
  des: "cont2",
  note: "cont2",
  pro_code: "NNB"
}, {
  des: "cont3",
  note: "cont3",
  pro_code: "QAS"
}];

const results = arr2.filter(({ pro_code: id1 }) => !arr1.some(({ pro_code: id2 }) => id2 === id1));

console.log(results);
```